Ubuntu on-prem upgrade 24.04 LTS to 24.10 and 24.10 clean image on Raspberry Pi 5 is crashing
On-prem upgrade from 24.04 LTS to 24.10 is crashing. Clean image after the language selection GNOME DE can't loaded stuck this point. I flashed the latest 25.04 daily build (dec 11) also have this issue. The rpi-eeprom on my pi5 is the latest 2024 11 12. My SD card is a Sandisk Extreme V30 U3 A2 (SDSQXA1-128G-GN6AA). The card is healthy and working well Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop LTS is runing fine. Clean instal i used the rpi-imager tool and EtchDroid app on my phone.
